# Transactions don't get restored when buying In-App Purchase again (Using MKStoreKit)

Tags: in-app-purchase, restore

I am  using MKStoreKit to handle all of my In-App Purchases in my app. 
When I buy my In-App Purchase the first time it works, but when I buy it again I get "You have already purchased this but it hasn't been downloaded. Tap OK to download it now." message. If I click ok I get "Failed Transaction" for some reason. It doesn't even call Restore Transactions, it calls "Transaction Failed" for some reason, even if I receive "You have already purchased" message. Why is this happening (I am using MKStoreKit 4)?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I'm experiencing the same troubles...

Comment: same issue here too. (with a non-consumable item)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what did the trick for me:

In MKStoreKitConfigs.h:

```
#define SERVER_PRODUCT_MODEL 0
```

The problem was I had this set to 1 when I was experimenting.